# jQuery accordion issue with template markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm having a little issue with this accordion script.

And I know why it's happening but I can't fix it. And I'm not sure it's possible to fixed it?

The accordion script i'm using is this and it's very easy to implement. http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/

The mark-up for this accordion is simple and semantic.

```
<ul class="menu">

    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="acitem">
            <li><a href="http://www.pivotx.net/">PivotX</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wordpress.org/">WordPress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.textpattern.com/">Textpattern</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://typosphere.org/">Typo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Weblog Tools</a>
        <ul class="acitem">
            <li><a href="http://www.pivotx.net/">PivotX</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wordpress.org/">WordPress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.textpattern.com/">Textpattern</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://typosphere.org/">Typo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- and so fourth -->

</ul>
```

This is the style of the markup that the script if designed to work with. And it works, see here... http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/CzZqZ/1/

But my problem is because I'm working with a template that I can't change the mark-up of, see my outputted markup below.

```
<ul class="menu">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul class="acitem">
                    <li><a href="http://www.pivotx.net/">PivotX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.wordpress.org/">WordPress</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.textpattern.com/">Textpattern</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://typosphere.org/">Typo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Weblog Tools</a>
            <ul class="acitem">
                    <li><a href="http://www.pivotx.net/">PivotX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.wordpress.org/">WordPress</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.textpattern.com/">Textpattern</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://typosphere.org/">Typo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</ul>
```

This the mark up that is outputted which is stupid.

Its outputting more than it needs to.

I've created a js fiddle for the markup above so you can see what is happening http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/CzZqZ/2/

It's not closing the others when a new one is opening...

Does anyone know how to fix the script so it work like the first jsfiddle, but with the crazy markup above?

Thanks very very much if anyone can help.

Josh

Comment: It doesn't seem to work even with valid markup, http://jsfiddle.net/CzZqZ/8/

Comment: why is the ul in the ul and not in a li????

Comment: @KevinB works fine for me, tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click handler, change to: `var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;`. With this it works as the other example you posted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CzZqZ/9/ - was testing while you were posting. ;-) Looks good to me, too.

Comment: Sorry had to wait 7mins as it got answered so quick - got distracted! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the class 'noaccordian" to your "ul" elements that you want to expand/collaspse on.

Example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <ul class="noaccordion">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Click Here</a>
            <ul class="acitem">
```